# ASP.NET HttpHandler not called unless there is a Session

Tags: .net, session, httphandler, ihttphandler

I have created a very simple ASP.NET HttpHandler and for some reason it is not being called unless the user is logged on.  I have it assigned to handle PNG images. For a first time visitor to the website, the handler is not called. After they logon, then it is called. I am using .NET 4, IIS7 on Windows 7 in Classic mode.  The PNG images requested do not exist in the file directory.

```
namespace MyNS
{
   public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler 
   {
       public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }
       public void ProcessRequest( HttpContext context ) 
       { }
   }
}
```

In my web.config, I have ...

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
   <add name="MyPNG" path="*.png" verb="*" type="MyNS.MyHttpHandler" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,bitness64" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: you surely do not need to hardcode a path like this in the web.config: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

Comment: What are security settings on your web.config?

Comment: @Davide, what path would I use?

Comment: @Emmanuel - anonymous is enabled, and forms authentication is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you are using IIS7 in classic mode, you must setup config in two places: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx).

Also you need to exclude your handler from authentication:

```
<location path="myhandler URL">
            <system.web>
                    <authorization>
                            <allow users="*"/>
                    </authorization>
            </system.web>
</location>
```

## UPDATE

OK, here is what I mean:

```
<location path="*.png">
            <system.web>
                    <authorization>
                            <allow users="*"/>
                    </authorization>
            </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: You may be on to something here, but there is not a URL for an IHttpHandler.

Comment: Yes there is. It is the path => `path="*.png"`

Comment: Thanks, this solved it, but I guess a little confused still.  If I place an actual image in the path, it displays without the location setting (via normal http request).  But, if the image file does not exist, then the location is required for the http handler to be invoked. So, it appears that I must go and set a location setting for all possible image paths now. While, if I have real image files there they work fine without no authentication.  Strange.

Comment: Yes you would have to. But I imagine your images are mostly located in one central directory so should be easy. There might be a catch-all format like `*/*.png` which is worth trying.